# responsive images inside a full width div

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, image-scaling

I have this markup:

```
<div class="girls" style="text-align:center; margin-top:100px">
    <img src="images/1.png" />
    <img src="images/2.png" />
    <img src="images/3.png" />
    <img src="images/4.png" />
```

and this css (I'm using Twitter Bootstrap) :

```
img {

    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 0;
    -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
```

}

The images have equal width and height and are displayed inline.

On my resolution are ok, fit the entire width (1366px), but on lower resolutions the images don't fit.
So, I need to keep the proportions on every screen resolution ( lower than 1366px in my case)

I've found this  [picturefill](https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill)

Which I think is helpful for me, but I'm thinking that it's a simpler solution for my case because I have 4 images which I need to display them horizontally and make them scale on every resolution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Twitter Bootstrap, then use markup properly like in [Twitter Bootstrap documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem):

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span3">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x400"/>
    </div>
    <div class="span3">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x400"/>
    </div>
    <div class="span3">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x400"/>
    </div>
    <div class="span3">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x400"/>
    </div>
<div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zNLBG/

Answer (score 1):

You can set the style `width` attribute of the images to 25%, without specifying height. That's gonna work if you're always putting 4 images, they have the same width between them and your container div is always at 100%.

HTH

Francisco

Comment: I've tried to set the images on 25% and remove the height:auto; but If I resized the browser there are still collapsing.

Comment: Ok, I just tried it and I had to watch for 2 things: 1) Don't leave space between images, and 2) Add this style attribute to your container div: `white-space: nowrap`. For me it worked even while resizing the broswer.