# responsive css background property

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have this markup :

```
 <ol class="carousel-indicators">

 <li data-target="#ShowCarousel-03" data-slide-to="0" class="active">
    <h4>Title</h4><br/><h5>Text</h5><br/><span>+</span>
 </li>

 <li data-target="#ShowCarousel-03" data-slide-to="1">
    <h4>Title</h4><br/><h5>Text</h5><br/><span>+</span>
 </li>

 <li data-target="#ShowCarousel-03" data-slide-to="2">
    <h4>Title</h4><br/><h5>Test</h5><br/><span>+</span>
 </li>

 <li data-target="#ShowCarousel-03" data-slide-to="3">
    <h4>Title</h4><br/><h5>Text</h5><br/><span>+</span>
 </li>
```

and this CSS :

```
.carousel-indicators li{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    background: url(images/triangle.png) no-repeat;
    width:320px;
    height:176px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align:center;
}
```

and the container div of my markup have a width set to **100%**

On my actual resolution (1366px wide) the li elements are aligned good, but when I resize my browser the elements are not aligned.

I'm using twitter bootstrap framework.

My question is how can I make this elements scale when the resolution is lower?

Thanks!

Comment: Post a jsFiddle, and tell us what you expect the elements to do at a smaller size.

Comment: I guess it's an update to this question from you earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15822493/responsive-images-inside-a-full-width-div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For responsive design you could use bootstrap grid system in your carousel by adding proper class to your code `.span4` `.span8` etc. It will resize your carousel with the browser size, but grid system has fixed size that might not fit your needs. Then you need overwrite some sizes with your own css but that may be hard to handle if you already use grid system in your site.

This is the doc site [grid system](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem)

Second approach is to use `em` or `%` for your carousel elements size and body element. With some media queries http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/ you can set how carousel changes in lower resolutions. 1 em will usually be equal to 16px. Calculation of your new em size is bit tricky, you divide `1` by parent container size, whitch is body element with `16px` font-size and multiply by your current `px` size:

```
1/16px*320px = 20em
```

CSS:

```
body {
    font-size:1em; /* 16px */
}

.carousel-indicators li{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    background: url(images/triangle.png) no-repeat;
    width:20em; /* 1/16px*320px = 20em */
    height:11em; /* 1/16px*176px = 20em */
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Tip. If you want that background image is scalled too use `background-size` property as well.

```
background-size:20em 11em;
```

Size for screen lower then 1170px:

```
@media (max-width:1170px){
   body {
      font-size: 0.875em; /* 14px */
   }
@media (max-width:800px){
   body {
      font-size: 0.75em; /* 12px */
   }
```

Your `li` element width would automaticaly change to `0.875em*20em = 17.5em` in resolution lower then 1170px and `0.75em*20em = 15em` in resolution lower then 800px.

Hope that helps!